# Voltage regulator IC with positive and negative voltage output

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need to save space on PCB and have to convert voltage from +48 to +9, -9 and virtual ground. Is there a single IC that could do that?

Comment: At what power output?

Comment: the current is really small, several miliamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it, for just a few milliamps, with two zeners and a resistor.

If you did it this way you could probably get away with a 1206 SMD resistor (0.5W) and a dual series SOT23 zener, in total smaller than most linear regulator packages. Here is a possible circuit (output is 9.1V per rail):

```
      ____
48V -|10k_|-+-- 9V
            |
         |__|__
           / \ |  9.1V
          /___\
            |
            |
            +-- GND
            |
         |__|__
           / \ |  9.1V
          /___\
            |
Source COM -+-- -9V
```

Comment: i did exactly that, worked perfect: http://blog.hardcore.lt/mic/archives/010942.html

Answer (score -1):

You need a DC/DC converter.  I suggest browsing the following websites where you should find something suitable

http://www.mornsun-power.com/cn/Index.html

http://www.xppower.com/

http://www.murata-ps.com/

Comment: Those sites don't seem to offer components (question seeks to save space), let alone small, low-power, board-level modules.  Also, given some fairly specific requirements it's a very vague answer.

Comment: The question actually asks for a single IC that will do it, not components - should I downvote the other answer?  The links will give you a solution, if you take the time to look through properly

Comment: Thomas' solution was compact, even if it wasn't a single IC per se.  Since it answers the spirit of the question, if not the letter, it probably doesn't need a downvote.  In any case, this discussion should be a comment to that answer.

Comment: @Nick T - Those sites certainly do offer components and low-power board-level modules. I found compatible modules from [Mornsun](http://www.mornsun-power.com/UploadFiles/pdf/PWA_CS-2W%20&%20PWB_CS-2W_EN.pdf), [XPPower](http://www.xppower.com/pdfs/SF_IA.pdf), and [Murata](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/ncl/kdc_mea.pdf).  I agree that the answer could do more to flesh out the search process, but there's no need to downvote it.

Comment: FWIW I`m not into spoon feeding people answers, a pointer in the right direction will certainly help in the long run :-)